# Monitoring Hard Faults on Windows Server 2003 using PerfMon

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory

Google hasn't helped me. Is there a way to track only the number of hard faults (to the page file on disk) using PerfMon? The Page Faults/Sec counter mixes hard and soft faults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the performance counter you're looking for is called **"Memory: Pages/sec."**

From this TechNet article [Useful Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746253.aspx):

> Pages/sec is the number of pages read
>   from the disk or written to the disk
>   because they were not in memory when
>   needed (that is, the number of page
>   faults that required disk access). The
>   counter includes paging traffic
>   generated when the cache accesses file
>   data for applications.

Comment: Separate read and write counters are also available and you really should monitor both. Hard read faults are normal (this is how most executable code should be loaded), but write faults should be zero under normal load.